# How to use directions api to get distances in excel (using JSON in VBA)

Tags: json, excel, vba, google-directions-api

I'm trying to get the distances between two points into an excel file. (Based on Dutch zip codes ,city or adressline)

I have found some information online and went with what I found on https://syntaxbytetutorials.com/excel-function-to-calculate-distance-using-google-maps-api-with-vba/

Short summary:

- I created an API key for the directions API
- I imported VBA-JSON from https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/releases
- Enabled the references like scripting runtime, WINHTTP
- Copied the macro in excel as below

```
Function TRAVELDISTANCE(origin, destination, apikey)

   Dim strUrl As String
   strUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" & origin & "&destination=" & destination & "&key=" & apikey
    
   Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
   With httpReq
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .Send
   End With
    
   Dim response As String
   response = httpReq.ResponseText
    
   Dim parsed As Dictionary
   Set parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
   Dim meters As Integer
    
   Dim leg As Dictionary
    
    
   For Each leg In parsed("routes")(1)("legs")
       meters = meters + leg("distance")("value")
   Next leg
    
    
    
   TRAVELDISTANCE = meters

End Function
```

Now when I use the formula in excel I get an #Value error.

- TRAVELDISTANCE(D2;=Setup!$B$2;Setup!$B$1)
  D2 being the zipcode origin '8311 PA', Setup!B2 being the destination 'Coöperatie "De Valk Wekerom" UA, Groeneveld, Meppel'
  If I replace D2 and Setup!B2 with 'United states Capitol' and 'White house' The formula returns 4326 so 4,3KM distance.
  So I know the request (API key) works, I also know that the JSON parsing works.

What could cause the problem when using Dutch adresses? I have tried with plain text like street names, city names, zip codes etc

Comment: The google distance api doesn't seem to like the `ö` character.  I don't know about the zipcode but there's probably an issue there also. Changing `ö` to `o` and using something like `Amsterdam, Netherlands` for the other address returns a distance of  about 123km (in different code, but using the same api). Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've tried different variations but keep up ending in a values error. No idea why, if I enter the search string in my webbrowser I can see it returns proper directions and a distance.

Comment: Did you get it to work with just a `o`? If not, what is the error message being returned?

Comment: It didn't work with just the 'o'. Using only Meppel, Netherlands and Lunteren, Netherlands results in the same. The only error I get is in excel: #waarde which is #Value.

Comment: **Not** the error message in Excel. You need to see the error message in the JSON being returned from the API call. You can access it in the immediate window by placing a break point after the JSON has been parsed, then, if I recall correctly, typeing `?JSON("error_message")` or something similar (*expand the JSON in the locals window to see the exact dictionary key*)

Comment: Hi A. van Esveld, I'm having the exact same problem right now. Did you find any solution for the #VALUE! error?